# Line break in table cell PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to perform several line break (br) in my table cell.
But I have problem with the syntax.

Below is my code to perform line break (br) within a single cell, but it doesn't work.
How should I go about doing it?

```
echo("<tr><td>".$row[0]. 
                <br/> 
                $row[1]. 
                <br/> $row[2]. 
                <br/> 
                "<img src=images/".$row["skuCode"]."_1.jpg>".
                <br/>
                <a href=viewProductItem.php?skuCode=".$row[0].">View</a>".
                 "</td></tr>");
```

Comment: You forgot the quotes around the `<br/>`s

Comment: don't echo multiline text like that. either break out of PHP mode, or at least use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc). Then you won't run into the problem of forgetting quote, or having to escape quotes.

Answer (score 5):

You're not using quotes properly, but I think it would be much easier to use a heredoc.

```
echo <<<HTML
    <tr><td>$row[0]<br/>$row[1]<br/>$row[2]<br/>
    <img src=images/$row[skuCode]_1.jpg<br/>
    <a href=viewProductItem.php?skuCode=$row[0]>View</a>
    </td></tr>
HTML;
```

Comment: Heredoc is the best solution for multi-lined strings. +1

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the quotes around the `<br/>`s , try:

```
echo("<tr><td>".$row[0]. 
                "<br/>" .
                $row[1]. 
                "<br/>". $row[2]. 
                "<br/>" .
                "<img src=images/".$row["skuCode"]."_1.jpg>".
                "<br/>".
                "<a href=viewProductItem.php?skuCode=".$row[0].">View</a>".
                 "</td></tr>");
```

Or alternatively:

```
echo("<tr><td>{$row[0]} 
                <br/> 
                {$row[1]} 
                <br/> {$row[2]} 
                <br/> 
                <img src=images/.$row[skuCode]._1.jpg>
                <br/>
                <a href=viewProductItem.php?skuCode={$row[0]}>View</a>.
                 </td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to open and close the quotes in your string:

```
<?php

echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."<br/>".$row[1]."<br/>".$row[2]."<br/><img src=images/".$row["skuCode"]."_1.jpg><br/><a href=viewProductItem.php?skuCode=".$row[0].">View</a></td></tr>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "<tr><td>{$row[0]}<br/>{$row[1]}<br/>{$row[2]}<br/><img src=\"images/{$row['skuCode']}_1.jpg\"><br/><a href=viewProductItem.php?skuCode=\"{$row[0]}\">View</a></td></tr>";
```

You forgot to wrap the br tags around brackets, also you can use curly braces to never have to exit out of your string and concat it in php

```
echo "String with $variable works";
echo "String with {$array['key']} works with curly bracers."
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make its HTML output well-formatted, then you could check this:

```
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "  <td>" . $row[0] . "<br />\n";
echo "  " . $row[1] . "<br />\n";
echo "  " . $row[2] . "<br />\n";
echo '  <img src="images/' . $row["skuCode"] . '_1.jpg"><br />' . "\n";
echo '  <a href="viewProductItem.php?skuCode=' . $row[0] . '">View</a></td><br />' . "\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
```

Or this:

```
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "  <td>" . $row[0] . "<br />\n";
echo "  " . $row[1] . "<br />\n";
echo "  " . $row[2] . "<br />\n";
echo "  <img src=images/" . $row["skuCode"] . "_1.jpg><br />\n";
echo "  <a href=viewProductItem.php?skuCode=" . $row[0] . ">View</a></td><br />\n"
echo "</tr>\n";
```

Or if you did not like those, look at this:

```
echo("<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "\n" .
                "<br />\n" .
                $row[1] . "\n" .
                "<br />" . $row[2] . "\n" .
                "<br />\n" .
                "<img src=images/" . $row["skuCode"] . "_1.jpg>\n" .
                "<br />\n" .
                "<a href=viewProductItem.php?skuCode=" . $row[0] . ">View</a>\n" .
                 "</td></tr>\n");
```